# sls alexa auth returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-plugins

I have recently started working on alexa serverless. I have followed the steps as mentioned in a serverless blog https://serverless.com/blog/how-to-manage-your-alexa-skills-with-serverless/

I have installed the serverless and created security profile and updated the Web settings with allowed return url i.e, https 127.0.0.1:9090
After this I ran the command sls alexa auth. From here I am getting error like this
[image]

I am unable to find whats happening behind the screens. whats with code. Required environment variables are set.Can somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Amazon Developer Portal](https://developer.amazon.com/). Choose Login With Amazon > Security Profiles > Edit > Web Settings.

Make sure you have the Allowed URL field filled in with your IP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I updated my **Allowed Origin** and **Allowed Return URLS** to the following and it worked. *Here is a screenshot.*

[image]

**Link:** 
https://developer.amazon.com/settings/console/securityprofile/web-settings/update.html